# Book recommendation on linear and nonlinear regression

Tags: book-recommendation, regression, linear-regression, regression-analysis

I am doing a very complex and in-depth course on regression (studying math), but the professor is flying through it and the book often does the same, or is very hard to understand. I wanted to know if you know any books particularly good for learning (for a beginner) on the subject? For me, the most important part is simplicity (no unnecessary long texts) without leaving out any steps in the explanation, staying formal but hopefully also going into some depth.  Hopefully some answers might take some of the frustration out of learning, and speed up the process!

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I found the Econometricians' approach very clear and solid. As a math student, it shouldn't be hard for you to read this book
[Econometrics by Bruce E. Hansen](https://perhuaman.files.wordpress.com/2014/06/econometrics-bruce-hansen-2014.pdf)

Comment: Promising, I will keep it in mind!

Answer (score 0):

The Manga Guide to Regression Analysis (ISBN 1593277288) might be a nice complement to the heavy-going text books. It covers multiple linear regression and logistic regression, but not non-linear regression. The calculations are all shown, and the examples are realistic enough.

Comment: Thanks! I would like a book that includes nonlinear regression, but I might take a look anyway over the break